# Placing link inside Js button

Tags: javascript, button, hyperlink

Im a newbeginner and having problems as the title says.

Im trying to write the code here but the editor shows the results so i posted pictures instead.

Original

[image: code]

without any link inside the button;

I thought it was as easy as just putting the a href link inside the span so here is the result;

[image: modified code]

Any experienced users out there who knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Paste your code with 4 leading spaces. Please visit the [help] to see more abut how to ask. You cannot nest links by the way

Comment: Instead of posting images, just paste your code into the question.

Comment: You have `a` tag inside an `a` tag? That won't work.

Comment: @torazaburo is correct. according to the HTML spec, `a` elements may not contain any other interactive elements. Try instead replacing `href='javascript:void(0);'` with `href="http://www.nbfbildeler.no"` on the top `a` tag and remove the inner one.